# Textview cannot be updated, except move to another fragment first

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, roomdb

Excuse me, I got an error updating textview `tv_cart_realprice2` using `item.hargaproduk` data while in app inspection `item.hargaproduk` is updated. it cannot updated automatically, it need to move to another fragment than back to the fragment where the recyclerview belong. how to fix this? thank you
here is the code :

```
class CartAdapter(
    private val listItems: ArrayList<Cart>,
    private val listener: OnAdapterListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder>()
{

    private lateinit var database: CartRoomDatabase
    private lateinit var dao: CartDao

    interface OnAdapterListener{
        fun onTambah(total: Int)
        fun onKurang(total: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartViewHolder {
        val view = ItemcartBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return CartViewHolder(view)
    }

    class CartViewHolder( binding:ItemcartBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        var tvNamaProduk = binding.tvNamaprodukfin
        var tvHargaProduk = binding.tvHargaprodukfin
        var tvStokProduk = binding.tvBanyakstok
        var tvGambarProduk = binding.ivCartitem
        var tvCartRealPrice = binding.tvCartRealprice
        var lnCartTambahProduk = binding.lnCartTambahproduk
        val llItemCartDeleteItem = binding.llItemcartDeleteitem
        val btnTambahProduk = binding.btnCartTambahproduk
        val ivTambahStok = binding.ivTambahstok
        val ivKurangStok = binding.ivKurangstok
        var tvCartRealPrice2 = binding.tvCartRealprice2
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listItems.size

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun updatecart(cart: Cart) {
        dao.update(cart)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var sharedPreferences = holder.itemView.context.getSharedPreferences("sp_login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var idlogin = sharedPreferences.getString("login_id", null)
        var loginkey = sharedPreferences.getString("login_key", null)

        database = CartRoomDatabase.getDatabase(holder.itemView.context.applicationContext)
        dao = database.getCartDao()
        var item = listItems[position]
        var lastItems = listItems.last()
        holder.tvNamaProduk.text = item.namaproduk

        if (item == lastItems){
            holder.lnCartTambahProduk.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            holder.lnCartTambahProduk.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        Glide.with(holder.tvGambarProduk)
            .load(item.gambarproduk)
            .error(R.drawable.bannerwelcome)
            .into(holder.tvGambarProduk)

        when(loginkey){
            "user" -> {
                holder.tvCartRealPrice2.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                holder.tvCartRealPrice.text = item.hargastart.toString()
                holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                val apiService = ApiService.getInstance().create(ApiEndpoint::class.java)
                apiService.getdataproduct(item.idproduk).enqueue(object : Callback<ProductResponse>{
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductResponse>, response: Response<ProductResponse>) {
                        val responsestok = response.body()!!.datadata[0].stok!!.toInt()
                        holder.ivTambahStok.setOnClickListener {
                            if (item.stokproduk < responsestok){
                                item.stokproduk++
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*item.hargastart
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "ecer",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            } else{
                                item.stokproduk = responsestok
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*item.hargastart
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "ecer",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            }
                        }
                        holder.ivKurangStok.setOnClickListener {
                            if (item.stokproduk > 0){
                                item.stokproduk--
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*item.hargastart
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "ecer",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk
                                    )
                                updatecart(data)
                                holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            } else {
                                item.stokproduk = 0
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*item.hargastart
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "ecer",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "error $t", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                })
            }
            "reseller" -> {
                    holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()
                    holder.tvCartRealPrice.text = item.hargaproduk.toString()
                    holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                    holder.tvCartRealPrice2.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                ///udah bener///
                val apiService = ApiService.getInstance().create(ApiEndpoint::class.java)
                apiService.getdataproduct(item.idproduk).enqueue(object : Callback<ProductResponse>{
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductResponse>, response: Response<ProductResponse>) {
                        val responsestok = response.body()!!.datadata[0].stok!!.toInt()

                        holder.ivTambahStok.setOnClickListener {
                            item.stokproduk+=5
                            val hargaPotonganPerItem = 1000
                            val potonganHarga = when {
                                item.stokproduk == 5 -> hargaPotonganPerItem
                                item.stokproduk >= 10 -> hargaPotonganPerItem * 2
                                else -> 0
                            }
                            if (responsestok in 0..4){
                                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Maaf, stok produk sudah berada dibawah 5, silahkan pilih produk yang lain", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                            else if(responsestok in 5..9){
                                var maxStockCanBuy = minOf(responsestok, item.stokproduk)
                                maxStockCanBuy -= item.stokproduk
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = maxStockCanBuy.toString()

                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)

                            }
                            else if (responsestok in 10..20){
                                var maxStockCanBuy = minOf(responsestok, item.stokproduk)
                                maxStockCanBuy -= item.stokproduk

                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = maxStockCanBuy.toString()
                                item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            } else {
                                if (item.stokproduk == 5){
                                    holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()

                                    ///udah bener nih///
                                    item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                    val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                    var data =
                                        Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                            namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                            hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                            gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                            stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                    updatecart(data)
                                    ///
                                    //holder.tvHargaProduk.text = item.totalperproduk.toString()
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "${item.hargaproduk}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                                } else if (item.stokproduk == 10  || item.stokproduk >= 10){
                                    holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()

                                    item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                    val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                    var data =
                                        Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                            namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                            hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                            gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                            stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                    updatecart(data)
                                    listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "jumlah item tidak valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        holder.ivKurangStok.setOnClickListener {
                            item.stokproduk-=5
                            if (item.stokproduk > 0){
                                val hargaPotonganPerItem = 1000
                                val potonganHarga = when {
                                    item.stokproduk == 5 -> hargaPotonganPerItem
                                    item.stokproduk >= 10 -> hargaPotonganPerItem * 2
                                    else -> 0
                                }
                                if (item.stokproduk == 5){
                                    holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()

                                    item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                    val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                    var data =
                                        Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                            namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                            hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                            gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                            stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                    updatecart(data)
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "${item.hargaproduk}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                                } else if (item.stokproduk >= 10 ){
                                    holder.tvStokProduk.text = item.stokproduk.toString()

                                    item.totalperproduk = item.stokproduk*(item.hargastart - potonganHarga)
                                    val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                    var data =
                                        Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                            namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = item.hargastart - potonganHarga,
                                            hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                            gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                            stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                    updatecart(data)
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "${item.hargaproduk}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                    listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Maaf, stok produk sudah berada dibawah 5, silahkan pilih produk yang lain", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                }
                            } else if (item.stokproduk == 0){
                                holder.tvStokProduk.text = "0"
                                holder.tvCartRealPrice.text = "0"
                                holder.tvCartRealPrice2.text = "0"

                                item.totalperproduk = 0
                                val getitemcart = holder.tvStokProduk.text.toString().toInt()
                                var data =
                                    Cart(no = item.no, noproduk = item.noproduk, idproduk = item.idproduk,
                                        namaproduk = item.namaproduk, hargaproduk = 0,
                                        hargastart = item.hargastart,
                                        gambarproduk = item.gambarproduk, jenisboronganproduk = "grosir",
                                        stokproduk = getitemcart, totalperproduk = item.totalperproduk, beratproduk = item.beratproduk)
                                updatecart(data)
                                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "${item.hargaproduk}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                listener.onTambah(item.totalperproduk)
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "Maaf, stok produk sudah berada dibawah 5, silahkan pilih produk yang lain", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context, "error $t", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                })
            }
        }

        holder.llItemCartDeleteItem.setOnClickListener {
            dao.delete(listItems[position])
            listItems.removeAt(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, listItems.size)
        }

        holder.btnTambahProduk.setOnClickListener {
            val fragmentManager = holder.itemView.context.findFragmentManager()
            if (fragmentManager != null) {
                // Perform the fragment transaction here
                val targetActivity = Dashboard_bottombar()
                val targetFragment = DashboardFragment_idle(targetActivity)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, targetFragment)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
    }

}

private fun Context.findFragmentManager(): FragmentManager?{
    val activity = this as? FragmentActivity
    return activity?.supportFragmentManager
}
```

whats wrong with my code? i need to update update `tv_cart_realprice2` automatically without move to another fragment.